# Amazon s3 query string authentication beyond 7days

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is it possible to enable query string authentication in s3 urls for more than 7 days(preferably indefinite). Currently it is set to 7 days. I want url level authentication only. Any other method possible are also welcome